# Error:$ is not defined in html5 Javascript

Tags: php, html

i am working in DOM i want to run marquee on header through given below library. this is my error below. Please help me out. theres an error of `$` which is not defined according code but I have already defined. The marquee is actually not working on `Mac Safari` browser.

```
Error:$ is not defined
```

Code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee/master/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="myfunction()" class="marquee" style="width: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
<script>
function myfunction(){
  $('#marquee').marquee();
}
</script>
```

the library is already included of jquery.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but have you tried using a more recent version of jQuery? The library may not expect you to use a 1.x one.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `<div class='marquee'>` element by using a id selector `$("#marquee")`.

Try using `$(".marquee")` instead.

[More info about jQuery selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp)

Comment: I don't think this will work, since `$` is still undefined.

Comment: yes it still shows the same result of $ is not defined

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with some corrections as said above.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee/master/jquery.marquee.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="myfunction()" class="marquee" style="width: 300px; overflow: hidden;"> hello </div>
<script>
  function myfunction() {
    alert("marquee");
    $('.marquee').marquee();
  }

</script>
```

Check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ntpuce0h/)